# Why I can't open my JavaFX .jar file that I exported from Eclipse?

Tags: java, javafx, executable-jar

I am trying to export a javaFx project I made in eclipse into a Runnable Jar file. When I export, I get this

[image: export message].

The jar file is successfully sent to my Applications folder, but when I try to run it I get this

[image: error message].
I have been trying to figure out how to open the java console to see the error messages, but it seems Apple has removed that feature on OS High Sierra.

Running the jar form a command line I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

The app works perfectly when I run it within eclipse.

Edit: This is the current error I am getting when trying to run it in the console with 'java -jar'[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTRxE.png)

Comment: Run it from Terminal and check the stack trace.

Comment: Gotcha I did that and here is the error message I got: Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Comment: Is `application.Main` the starting point of this application ?  If so look into your `jar` file. Does the `MANIFEST.MF` list a `application.Main` as main class ? Is there a `Main.class` in the jar ?

Comment: @c0der How do I go about looking into my jar file if it's a file and not a folder? Also yes application.Main is the starting point.

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: 11.0.1 for java and javac

Comment: @JimmyD it is an archive. You open it with 7-zip or alike: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001343.htm

Comment: @c0der Ok so I looked into my jar file. Within it there are two folders, one named 'application' that has all the files from my project including Main.class. It wouldn't let me open it, however, because it said it was from an unknown developer, so I went into my settings and allowed files from unknown developers. I thought that might have been the problem but I've been getting the same error messages. The other folder is titled META-INF and has one file inside of it, the MANIFEST.MF file you mentioned. It does list application.Main as the main class

Comment: If [tutorials](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/web/selenium/export-eclipse-java-project-as-runnable-jar.html) do not help try posting the content of `MANIFEST.MF` and the directory structure  of the jar.  A link to the jar itself may also help.

Comment: @c0der Here's a link to the jar file [https://www.mediafire.com/file/p610xfc4ffv6o2f/CalculatorFX.jar/file]. Also from the eclipse console I now see that whenever I run the app, I get this error message `WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 10.0.2`. The app still runs smoothly. Do you think that might be causing this?

Comment: There is no problem in the linked jar. It runs on my machine,

Comment: Hmm very interesting, must be something with my computer. Either way that's good to know though, since I just wanted to be able to put it on github for others. Any last ideas I could try to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: @c0der Quick update. I don't know if this is how it was before but now the MANIFEST.MF has this inside it `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: application.Main
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader`

Comment: Please [edit] and post all updates. Is the jar running now ?

Comment: Nope not on my computer. Some answers to similar problems on SO have mentioned having to use javafxpackager to package the jar on later java versions. Do you know anything about this?